# Data manipulation with power pivot, power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I am doing some simple projects with power pivot/query/bi. When I try to create the pivot table from the data model in power pivot, it will only display the data as below. Counted value will be displayed here. I want to display the actual value from the data model related to the relevant year.

[image]

But I want to display as below.

[image]

I think that I'll have to use measures for this task. but I'm in the early stages of the power pivot & power bi. Can someone help me to do this?

My pivot table fields are like below.

[image]

The "Attribute" field is generated by unpivoting Test value columns in the table.
My raw data table from file name "2022" for the year 2022 is like below. I need to create separate files for each year to enter test results for each name.

[image]

Comment: You are going to have an issue since you have text and numbers for `Value`. The measure you create will be Text. For your measure it could look like `Measure Value = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Value])`

Comment: If `SELECTEDVALUE` doesn't work, try `MIN` or `MAX`

Comment: Depending on any other requirements, you could generate this entire table in Power Query.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Some corrections are required with the SELECTEDVALUES() function. In my version of Excel SELECTEDVALUE() did not appear, but I used the VALUES() function and it worked.